# Android ListView with paging crashes

Tags: android

I have pageable ListView and its rows are being loaded asynchronously while scrolling down and sometimes the app just crashes. It's not happening on Android 2.3.3 but does happen on Android 4.0 and above.

Here is my stack trace:

```
03-07 15:23:02.450: D/AndroidRuntime(1545): Shutting down VM
03-07 15:23:02.450: W/dalvikvm(1545): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ccb930)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099953, class com.ui.PaginableListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4042)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 15:23:02.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAnd
```

It's part of the code, probably not very helpful ;/

```
protected DataResponse doInBackground(IRequest... reqs) {
    IRequest req = reqs[0];
    CancelStateHolder cancelStateHolder = new CancelStateHolder() {
        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return DataRequestTask.this.isCancelled();
        }
    };

    if (cacheKey != null) {
        try {
            CacheDogpileProtector.getInstance().acquire(cacheKey);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            cancel(true);
            ZLog.printStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

    reqExec.setParentTask(this);
    DataResponse resp = reqExec.execute(req, cancelStateHolder,
    cacheContext, cacheKey);
    if (resp == null) {
        Log.d(LOG, "resp == null");
    }
    return resp;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(DataResponse result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ZLog.d(LOG, "override onPostExecute");
    try {
        if (result.getJsonResponse() == null) {
            ZLog.i(LOG, "json is NULL (probably connection problem)   response text: " + result.getResponseText());
            throw new NASAException(R.string.exception_io);
        }
        ConsumptionStatus consumption = ConsumptionStatus.REQUEST_NOT_CONSUMED;
        if (onZadaneRequestCompletedListener != null) {
            consumption = onZadaneRequestCompletedListener.onZadaneRequestCompleted(PaginableListView.this, request, result);
        }

        switch (consumption) {
            case REQUEST_CONSUMED:
                 break;
            case REQUEST_UPDATE_METADATA:
                 wrapAndUpdate(result.getJsonResponse(), true);
                 break;
            case REQUEST_NOT_CONSUMED:
                 wrapAndUpdate(result.getJsonResponse(), false);
                 break;
         }
         if (onZadaneRequestCompletedListener != null) {
             onZadaneRequestCompletedListener.onZadaneRequestCompletedAfterWrap(PaginableListView.this, request, result, lastFetchedPage);
         }
         setOnRefreshListener(properOnRefreshListener);
     } catch (NASAException e) {
         DialogHandler.handleError(mContext, e.getMessage(mContext));
     } finally {
         removeFooterView(footerView);
         actualTask = null;
     }
}

};
actualTask.executeCached(activity, cacheContext, request);
```

Comment: Are you loading your results using an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`?

Comment: What part of *"Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread."* you did not understand? I don't mean to be rude, it's an actual question :)

Comment: I'm using an AsyncTask.

Comment: m0skit0 I've checked it like thousand times and everything is modified in UI thread

Comment: Do you happen to reuse the array that you give the arrayadapter?

Comment: Can you add your loading code?  It's hard to guess at what you're doing beyond what your stack trace says without seeing some code.

Comment: Try calling yourListView.invalidateViews(); after the underlying list changes.

Comment: @JacekŁyp post your code

Comment: @Warpzit, the array is private and I'm pretty sure that it's not used somewhere else.

Comment: @Demonick, I've just put your line of code in like every method and it unfortunately didn't help :(.

Comment: @MCeley , Pragnani, what part of code, because this is a huge project, and the logic is spread throughout few classes.

Comment: Whichever part of the code does the actual updating of the adapter.

Comment: @MCeley I've added part of code.

Comment: Does `onZadaneRequestCompletedListener` use any sort of threading?  That's the only thing I can see that I'm not sure runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @MCeley it does not, I guess I'm stuck :(

Comment: This is just a complete guess but it stood out that you don't have this problem on 2.3.3 that uses a thread pool for AsyncTasks whereas 4.0+ doesn't.  Can you switch the execution of your task from `execute` to `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)` and let me know if that changes anything for Android 4.0+?  If that doesn't work then I'd be happy to work through this with you in the Android chat room. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25788/discussion-between-mceley-and-jacek-lyp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding something like this to your ListView:

```
    @Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    try {
        super.layoutChildren();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        ZLog.e(LOG, "This is not realy dangerous problem");
    }
}
```

If you add a headerview or a footerview ListView, and when you notifyDataSetChanged(), it will change the mItemCount to the item count of real adapter, but the right side will return the fake itemcount which has added the headercount and footercount:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ListView.java?av=f#1538

Answer (score 0):

As your stack trace says, you cannot update the contents of an adapter using a background thread.  Since you're using an `AsyncTask`, fixing this is pretty easy.  Instead of updating your adapter in `doInBackground`, update it in `onPostExecute`.

Here's a sample of what this could look like.

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Object results = getResults(); /* Replace with your own result fetching code */
    return results;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    /* Update your adapter here using the returned results. */
    myAdapter.addNewData(result);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```